# jQuery UI tabs doesn’t calculate width properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I’m using jQuery UI tabs on a page. I’m applying padding to the content panels. But on page load, it seems the inner width of the text is calculated as the parent’s width (not accounting for the padding) and then hangs outside the panel. But, if I select a new tab and go back to the original, it fixes itself (accounting for the padding).

Has any one had this issue before and if so, how can I remedy it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to avoid this is give same padding to the content on page load as it is given when switching between tabs.

Comment: How would I do this? My `padding` declaration is just in my site’s style sheet.

Comment: `$(".yourcontentdiv").css({padding: somevalue});` in your `$(document).ready()`